# MySql query to find records NOT between time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a project where the `from` and `to` time are given and I have to find out if any other vehicles are allocated on that time period.

For EG:
Vehicle 1 is allocated `FROM 2017-04-29 10:00:00 TO 2017-04-29 12:00:00` in the case table.

My use case: I should not be able to allocate the same vehicle in that time range.

So, How would I check if a vehicle is allocated / clashes with the time range? (IN mySQL)

Here is where I am so far:

```
 SELECT 'vehicle_code' 
 FROM   'case' 
 WHERE  'from_time' <= '2017-04-29 11:00:00'
 AND    'to_time' >= '2017-04-29 13:00:00'
```

Comment: To check for overlapping intervals you check for `start1 < end2 and end1 > start2`, to exclude those rows: `NOT (start1 < end2 and end1 > start2)`. Depending on your logic you might use `>=/<=` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess **the specific** vehicle with `%VEHICLE_CODE%` you are trying to allocate cannot be already allocated within that time range, so you are not interested in any vehicle but in a specific one.

You have an overlap if at least of this three things occurs:

1. The `from_time` of an allocation falls within your requested period
2. The `to_time` of an allocation falls within your requested period
3. The whole allocation falls into your requested period

Then you can use this query

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `case`  
WHERE vehicle_code = %VEHICLE_CODE% 
AND (from_time between '2017-04-29 11:00:00' AND '2017-04-29 13:00:00'
OR to_time BETWEEN '2017-04-29 11:00:00' AND '2017-04-29 13:00:00'
OR from_time < '2017-04-29 11:00:00' AND to_time > '2017-04-29 13:00:00');
```

With this query you ensure there isn't any allocation for **this** vehicle where the **from_time** or the **to_time** fall into the queried period or the whole period does.

If the query returns 0 you **don't** have an overlap. If it returns more than 0, you do have such an overlap.

Similarly to what @dnoeth told you, you could also **exclude** all entries where, either the to_time is less than the start of the queried interval **or** the from_time is greater than the end of queried interval. If any entry remains, this is an overlap. So you would have

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `case`  
WHERE vehicle_code = %VEHICLE_CODE% 
AND NOT (from_time > '2017-04-29 13:00:00'
OR to_time < '2017-04-29 11:00:00');
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you soo much! This works perfectly! You are awesome! :D

Comment: case is a reserved word

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, of course. I add quotation marks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether either of these times fall into time range of any other vehicle, e.g.:

```
SELECT vehicle_code
FROM `case`
WHERE from_time >= '2017-04-29 11:00:00' AND to_time <= '2017-04-29 11:00:00'

UNION

SELECT vehicle_code
FROM `case`
WHERE from_time >= '2017-04-29 13:00:00' AND to_time <= '2017-04-29 13:00:00'
```

If this query returns any row, it means another vehicle is already booked and hence, you need to show appropriate error message.

Comment: If this query returns any row, it ain't mysql ;-)